# Finding OSM edge variations over time using osmnx?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I'm looking to compare changes to OSM over time for a given location (e.g., NYC). I've created OSM graphs of NYC at two different timestamps using the overpass_settings in ox.config(). I'd like to find all edge variations between the two OSM graphs (e.g., edges moving or being added or removed due to construction). I started with using a concatenation of u, v, key, and geometry as a unique id for each edge in both of the graphs (the idea of including geometry as part of the unique id was to capture the variation between the "same" edge at two different timestamps). However, from what I've read and also seen from manually exploring the two graphs as shapefiles, u, v, and key are not immutable over time. U, v, and key create a stable unique id within any particular OSM graph, but they may not create a stable unique id over time.

Is this an inherent limitation to OSM or is there a way to compare edge changes over time? If the above isn't clear, [this conversation](https://github.com/sharedstreets/sharedstreets-ref-system/issues/23) from the SharedStreets project describes what I'm looking to do, albeit within the SharedStreets framework.

Comment: You could try setting `simplify=False` in OSMnx, and then use `osmid` + `geometry` as the unique identifiers.

Comment: @gboeing, thank you for replying so quickly! Huge fan of OSMnx btw - thank you for continually adding awesome features. It looks like osmid is also mutable over time like u, v, and key, so wouldn't using osmid have the same issue? I'm already using simplify=False to get the raw OSM edges - that's a very critical piece of this puzzle.